# Why is a table called a relation in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Coming from a MySQL background I've been wondering for some time why a table is actually called a relation in postgresql. Does it have to do with the SQL:2008 ISO/ANSI standard? Because it confused the hell out of me and colleagues on the first few encounters with postgres.

I'm asking because knowing the reasoning behind it might clear up some things or might make the adoption a little easier.

Comment: Because it's a relational database: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_databases#Terminology

Comment: @MarkBannister: I think you mean to say, "It's a database **management system** that is considered relationally complete **by Codd's definition of that term**" ;)

Comment: How long is a piece of string?:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This originates from terminology used by academics, rather than that used by software engineers. You will find this occurs much with PostgreSQL and their documentation leaves you frequently in need of a technical dictionary if you are unfamiliar with it.

The formal language for databases is referred to as "Relational algebra".

As mentioned by mark bannister, this link may be helpful for terminology:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_databases#Terminology

**Edit**

To be clear on what I mean by this:
SQL is a standard that was written by industry (Oracle had a big part in it).  SQL does not mention relational algebra, indeed its origin was a language designed to be be easily human readable rather algebraic.

Relational algebra is in general the domain of the academic world and is not commonly used by the engineering world.

Posgresql community has greater ties with the academic community than other implementations and it seems that they chose their terminology from relational algebra rather than copying the engineers.  Some might argue that this is in error since PostgreSQL is a **SQL** database management system, rather than a **relational** database management system.

Comment: Thanks, I enjoyed the discussion. On reflection, I think this answer is too flawed to be rescued. I don't think your distinction between academics and software engineers has been properly justified, likewise your assertions about the relationship between relational algebra and SQL. I'm not comfortable with the definitions given in the Wikipedia article your have linked to. I have edited your answer to correct a factual misstatement, however.

Comment: Thanks. Me Too. I was thinking about that distinction last night. Where I was coming from is the way they are used. Relational Algebera is for working with the theory leading me to say "academic" (with a specific exception that vendors use it internally in an RDBMS). SQL is used to express implementation leading me to say "industry". The other thing in my mind was that I still have yet to see a time when relational algebera is used in documentation or discussion for the purposes of software development.

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you mean but I saw this article ([link](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2024658)) just the other day, which might be of some interest to you :) p.s. "I think this answer is too flawed to be rescued" -- ouch, that came out wrong. What I meant was, I'll stick to my own answer :)

Answer (score 4):

> Does it have to do with the SQL:2008 ISO/ANSI standard?

The Standard SQL specs have always purposely avoided the term "relation" and its derivatives.

A relation by definition has no attributes with duplicated names, no anonymous columns, no duplicate tuples and no nulls. The same cannot be said of a SQL table. If the postgreSQL documentation equates "relation" with "table" then they are using these terms loosely.

Answer (score 3):

Its just a way to name things. Some people have tables with rows and columns, others have relations with tuples and attributes. It's not postgresql specific, moreover using these other designations implies a certain way to organize your tables, see "relational model" in wikipedia.

Answer (score -2):

"Relation" actually covers several different types of database object: tables, views, sequences and indices are all relations. You can do a SELECT from any of those except indices. So think of "relation" as meaning "something you can get data from", with tables and views as being instances that work quite differently.

To some extent, that's also why you can say "tuples" and "attributes" instead of "rows" and "columns": rows and columns can be thought of as *table* constituents, whereas tuples and attributes are the more abstract concepts that also cover things like function or query output, which may not actually correspond to any real row or column. But this is as confusing as trying to distinguish between a "byte" and an "octet".

Not to mention: in a table, a tuple doesn't represent a *row*, it represents a *row version*: and distinguishing between tuples using the version information and presenting them as "rows" is what makes a table a table instead of just a collection of tuples. Kind of. And some of the tuple attributes aren't columns, they're additional metadata to manage the versioning.

Comment: "indices are all relations...  think of "relation" as meaning "something you can get data from" -- among many misstatements in this answer.